# How to prevent Local Notifications in Capacitor JS from opening the application?

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, capacitor

On Android, I'm utilizing the LocalNotifications API in an Ionic project with Capacitor JS (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications). So the user can respond directly to a notification, I've added some action types to the payload like this:

```
LocalNotifications.registerActionTypes({
    types: [
        {
            id: "workout-1",
            actions: [
                {
                    id: ":+1:",
                    title: "",
                    destructive: true,
                },
                {
                    id: ":muscle:",
                    title: "",
                    destructive: true,
                },
                {
                    id: "free_text",
                    title: "Respond",
                    input: true,
                },
            ],
        },
```

This enables the message to render like this:
[image]

However, even when tapping one of emojis, it opens the app. All I'd like it to do is trigger action performed on the emoji that was tapped. It works this way on iOS. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, is there any update on this? I am seeing this behavior as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up an event listener in your application setup phase:

```
LocalNotifications.addListener('localNotificationActionPerformed', (notification) => {
  const tappedActionId = notification.actionId;
  // TODO: do action depending on actionId
}
```

When user taps on notification or any action, app will open and this function will run. When user taps on notification (not action) `actionId = 'tap'`.